# Trouble to install graphic card (NVIDIA GT630) on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I tried by many ways to get my graphic card installed to get the correct resolution to my two screens.
I tried on ubuntu 16.10 but currently am on 14.04

One is 1920x1080 and the other is 1680x1050

My graphics card is a NVIDIA GT 630.

What I did most recently is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

(I searched and found the right number on NVIDIA website)

```
sudo reboot
```

I checked that I used the correct driver :

[image: Ubuntu softwares]

But I cannot see the correct resolutions for both my screens in X Server :

[image]

The max resolution I got for each screen is 1360*768 !

Here is a screen of the `xrandr --query` command :

[image]

(I also tried to download the .run from nvidia server and install it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> mode but it was unsuccessful to !
I did not succeed either by adding a new resoltuion by hand (with xrandr --addmode methods))

Here is the output of the `lspci -v` command to show my graphic card :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for the answer, I finally made it work !

Besides installing nvidia-367, I switched cables between my two screens :

I used the VGA for my Samsung SyncMaster S22B150 and it solved the problem for this one.

I put my ACER AL2216W on the DVI and it still wasn't working for it.

I added the following to my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file :

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    VendorName "ACER"
    ModelName "AL2216W"
    HorizSync 31 - 80
    VertRefresh 56 - 75
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "Device0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1680x1050"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I rebooted, and opening X server, I was able to chose the right resolution.
From here, I don't know exactly what I did becasue the resolution wouldn't stay after each reboot, but I know have the following /etc/X11/xorg.conf file :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: xconfig, VertRefresh source: xconfig
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    ModeLine       "1680x1050" 146.250 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1920x1200" 154.000 1920 1968 2000 2080 1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1920x1080" 173.000 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1792x1344" 204.800 1792 1920 2120 2448 1344 1345 1348 1394 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1600x1200" 175.500 1600 1664 1856 2160 1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1440x900" 106.500 1440 1520 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1400x1050" 155.800 1400 1464 1784 1912 1050 1052 1064 1090 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1360x768" 72.000 1360 1408 1440 1520 768 771 781 790 +hsync -vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 630"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: 1680x1050_60 +0+0, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1680+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    Modes       "1680x1050"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

From here, it wasn't enough, I had to enter the following lines in a shell :

```
gtf 1680 1050 60
```

It outputed :

```
# 1680x1050 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 65.22 kHz; pclk: 147.14 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  147.14  1680 1784 1968 2256  1050 1051 1054 1087  -HSync +Vsync
```

I used the Modeline and typed in :

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  147.14  1680 1784 1968 2256  1050 1051 1054 1087  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 1680x1050_60.00
xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1680x1050_60.00 --rate 60
```

AND IT WAS OK !!

When I reboot, at the login screen, my ACER screen still won't have the good resolution but as soon as I'm logged in, it's ok !

Comment: I'm glad to hear of your success with GT630 after reading so many failures. I might try my Nvidia GT650M + Intel hybrid soon using some of your answer.